# R variable string replacement in a data frame

Tags: string, r, replace

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(one=c("s1_below_10", "s2_below_20"), 
                 two=c("s3_above_10","s4_above_10"))
```

I want to replace all the strings by the number preceding the first underscore. In other words, the desired output is

```
1   3
2   4
```

I would like to know how I can perform this replacement (the dataset is very large). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The basic `gsub` call would be something like:

```
gsub("^.+?(\\d+)_.+","\\1",df$one)
[1] "1" "2"
```

Which you could `lapply` to each column:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, gsub, pattern="^.+(\\d+)_.+",replacement= "\\1"))
  one two
1   1   3
2   2   4
```

Comment: The above pattern will only grab the last digit of a multi digit number (which may be what was wanted, or not) because the first '.+' is greedy and will match as much as possible.  A simple correction of changing '.+' to '.+?' will make it non-greedy and let the \\d+ match multiple digits.

Answer (score 2):

If the values you want are *always* the second character of the string (which seems to be true of all your examples), you can do this with `substr`:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, substr, 2, 2))
```

Output:

```
  one two
1   1   3
2   2   4
```